# "Tag spag" on the tips of some of our tongues, but not others

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

Here's another plate full of tag spaghetti where we go out of our way to avoid being consistent.

Language tags:

Some languages get their very own tag all to themselves. [I brought this up years ago and lost to the opposing idea that a tag for every language is a great idea.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/974) (I wasn't convinced.)

- [georgian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/georgian) (2)
- [japanese](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) (6)
- [portuguese](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/portuguese) (1)
- [russian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian) (6)
- [spanish](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spanish) (4)
- [ukrainian](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukrainian) (2)

Yet we haven't followed through on that afterwards. Since then some tags created for individual languages have been merged into the `languages` tag. But others are still wild and free.

- [arabic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic)
- [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english)

Do we ignore the previous discussion and make them all synonyms of [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages)?

Or do we ignore the trend of not making new per-language tags and go through all current questions about languages to give them the correct specific tags, and de-synonymize the tags merged into [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) against the outcome of the previous discussion?

Answer (score 10):

As far as consistency goes, you are right -- we need to agree on a policy and follow it through.

I'm not convinced by your argument that all language-related questions should be tagged [languges](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languges) -- I mostly agree with [Andrew Grimm's answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1060) to the question you linked to. 
It's similar to [countries](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countries) -- not very informative, and unlikely many people are going to be interested in it.

However, I see problems with tag names such as [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [japanese](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese) etc., which may also refer to the nationality as well as the language itself. We already have the `-citizens` suffix for nationality. What I propose instead:

- Un-synonimize [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [arabic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) and any other language-related tag that currently exist.
- Rename existing language tags to have the suffix `-language`, even when language names are unambiguous, such as [telugu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telugu), [sanskrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanskrit), or whatever. This will facilitate searching for language questions if one is so inclined, by using `[*-language]` or similar as a query.
- Eliminate [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) altogether. Unlikely a question would need more than three language tags, which makes it superfluous.

I'm expecting your comments below. If there are disagreeing opinions on this, I'll move it to a separate question to have a contained discussion there.

---

**Update:**

Existing language tags (or at least, those I was able to find) are now renamed. [english](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english) and [arabic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic) were un-synonimized from [languages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) and were made synonyms to the newly-created [english-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-language) and [arabic-language](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arabic-language), respectively.

Comment: I agree with you 10000%

Comment: I'm not convinced by your argument that I presented any such argument, let alone tried to convince anybody of anything other than "we decided something then never went and did it". Can you show me this argument you attribute to me?

Comment: @hippietrail: I was referring to `I brought this up years ago and lost to the opposing idea that a tag for every language is a great idea. (I wasn't convinced.).` I also vaguely remember you being a proponent of having a single `languages` tag for all languages, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Oh in my old question, then you might be right. To me "languages" is a travel topic. "French" is not a travel topic. In fact the vast majority of questions on a given language are not very different from one another. "Do I need it? Should I learn it? How hard is it?" Can you show some points from the tagging guidelines, meta posts, and blog, as to how a tag for each foreign language can improve a travel site? It's not the same as programming languages on SO after all.

Comment: But we're getting ahead of ourselves. I have an opinion but the important thing is to first make it consistent one way or the other. Which way is less important.